# How would a provide a self-updating web application, delivered via docker image?

Tags: docker, deployment, updates

I would like to build in my web application, the ability to monitor updates, and install them, if the admin chooses to do so.

This functionality is *some-what* similar to what Jira does.

[image: Jira application update]

The question is, how would I perform this?

Let's assume I have full admin access to the docker host.

Maybe there is a tool out there?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

1. Have a seperate "update" docker container.
2. When starting an update, the web app communicates to host docker to startup the update container.
3. The update container will receive the new docker images then `docker save && docker load` into the host machine (can child containers do this?)
4. The update container will shutdown web container and start another web container (progress container) that just gives update progress on port 80.
5. The update container will update the web container with new image.
6. When complete, the update container will shutdown the progress container, and start the new web application.

Sorry if this isn't exactly a Q/A question, but I am wondering if there is a tool out there that does something like this, or maybe a tool that could be re purposed for this.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not an expert, but answering in case someone like me searches and finds this.

so maybe the answer is you wouldn't. docker container shall be immutable. so the way you update your webapp is by building a new docker image and deploying that.

see also:
[Can I push application updates to docker image without rebuilding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857095/can-i-push-application-updates-to-docker-image-without-rebuilding)